# Discord Bot in Python - Im trying to pick a random person from all the people with a specific role

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

So, i am trying to make a Discord Bot in Python. I'm just trying to make a bot that slaps a random person with the role "slapped". I've gotten everything to work but i cant figure out how to call for a random member with the role.
and if possible also limit it to who's currently online.
I'm decently good at python but new to discord bots. If you could help, id be grateful.
My code

```
import time
import discord
import random
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=',', description='Enjoy Being Slapped 
Randomly')
intervalM = random.randint(5,15)
#intervalS = integerM * 60

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(bot.user.name)

@bot.command()
async def slapInt(integer):
    await bot.say("Time Between Slaps is now... " + str(integer) + "min")
    intervalM = integer

@bot.command()
"""manually slap someone"""
async def slapMan(intervalM, user):
    #debug - await bot.say("oof " + str(intervalM))
    intervalS = float(intervalM) * 60
    await bot.say("Slapping someone in " + str(intervalS) + " seconds")
    for i in range(0,int(intervalS)+1):
        if i == int(intervalS):
            await bot.say(" just got slapped!")
            intervalM = random.randint(5,15)
            slap(intervalM)
        else:
            #await bot.say(i)
            time.sleep(1)

def slap(intervalM):
    intervalS = float(intervalM) * 60
    print("Slapping someone in " + str(intervalS) + " seconds")
    for i in range(0,int(intervalS)+1):
        if i == int(intervalS):
            print(" just got slapped!")
            intervalM = random.randint(5,15)
            slap(intervalM)
        else:
            #await bot.say(i)
            time.sleep(1)

bot.run('~~~~~~~~~')
slap(intervalM)
```

Comment: Could you start programming and add some sample when you encounter any trouble?

Comment: im not sure what you meant, but i want it to pick from a changing amount of people so if one person leaves or joins, i dont want to mess with it

Comment: Redact and change your token RIGHT NOW! You have just given anyone who cares to look full access to your bot. Redacting it is not enough as SO tracks edit history, so you must change it too.

Comment: @CollinS.Lawson Your token is still visible in the [edit history here](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/47248409/2). You'll need to contact a moderator and have it redacted. You can do that by raising a flag for moderator attention.

Comment: @EthanField ive changed the token, so that one should be unusable now

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
server = discord.Server(id='your_server_id')

def slap(intervalM):
    intervalS = float(intervalM) * 60
    print("Slapping someone in " + str(intervalS) + " seconds")
    for i in range(0,int(intervalS)+1):
        if i == int(intervalS):
            roleMembers = []
            for member in server.members:
                for role in member.roles:
                    if role.name == 'your_role_name' and member.status == 'online':
                        roleMembers.append(member)
            memberCount = len(roleMembers)
            randomNumber = random.randint(0, (memberCount -1)
            await bot.say(roleMembers[randomNumber].name + ' just got slapped!')
            intervalM = random.randint(5,15)
            slap(intervalM)
        else:
            #await bot.say(i)
            time.sleep(1)
```

(code is not tested)